# Model Driven form with ng2-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular2-forms, ng2-bootstrap, angular2-formbuilder

I've looked around and wasn't able to find anything definitive on this - can you use the ng2-bootstrap datepicker with an Angular2 model driven form, or does it only work with template forms?

The documentation describes the selector such that you'd use it as follows (as an example):

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="startDate" ></datepicker>
```

...which does seem to work.  Ideally I'd like to use it like this:

```
<datepicker formControlName="startDate" ></datepicker>
```

...but it doesn't seem to work that way out of the box.  Is there a way to use this module with model driven forms?  If not, is there a reasonable alternative that will work with model driven forms?  (I've also tried ng2-datepicker but there's an [outstanding bug](https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker/issues/66) that makes it inconvenient to use with SystemJS, which is unfortunate because it looks slick).

Comment: What happens when you use the first example? Are you getting errors? I've never used this library, but I think with ngModel and template forms, you need a `name` attribute

Comment: It works fine, you don't need a `name` attribute.  ...so if I were using template driven forms I'd be all set, but I prefer model driven forms.

Comment: Sorry I misread you're question. I read it as you were trying to use the first example, not the second. Ooops :-D

Comment: Can you show a complete example of the component and template. I'd like to try it out. I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: Valor software has full examples on their site.  Closest to mine would be the ones using SystemJS and Angular2 Quickstart.  Take a look: https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker.  Note that I've basically moved on to primeng as it seems to do what I'm looking for right out of the box.

Comment: You're right. looking at the source, model forms are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the primeNg set of controls and they have a calendar control with amazing functionality.  See it here:
[PrimeNg Calendar UI Control](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

Comment: That looks altogether great!  Thanks - I'll give that a shot.  It will be datepicker #4 on my quest for datepicker utopia but it certainly looks promising.  I'm not sure why did didn't show up more prominently in my searching so far...

Comment: if it works for you please mark as answer.  I'm using the calendar control in my app.  You probably didn't find it because its not a date picker but a calendar, although it has a build it datepicker functionality.

Comment: Will do - I'll have it figured out this afternoon. Looks good so far.

Comment: Works well, but I am having trouble applying any css to the input field.  I have tried using the `styleClass` (which embeds the input box within something styled the way I want, but doesn't style the input) and `inputStyleClass` which, from what I can tell, does nothing regardless of what css I associate with that class.   If I try to inline it, eg `<p-calendar inputStyle="background-color:#F4F9FF;" id="startDate" formControlName="startDate"></p-calendar>` I get the error; `Cannot find a differ supporting object 'background-color:#F4F9FF;'`.  Any idea how to successfully style the input field?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a big css scholar... There is a community forum run by primeNg, you can ask there or here...

Comment: Apparently it is a known bug that is fixed in beta 18, due to be released soon.

Answer (score 5):

I made simple wrapper for ng2-bootstrap datepicker to use it with ReactiveFormsModule. It uses moment, so you may improve it for your needs.

**[Live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/DxklfxcSH9j8Z4UILqsY)**

**custom-datepicker.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, forwardRef, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment';

let DATEPICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR: Provider = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomDatepickerComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-datepicker[formControlName]',
  template: `
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="datePickerValue"></datepicker>
  `,
  providers: [DATEPICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomDatepickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  change = (_: any) => {};
  _customDatePickerValue;
  _datePickerValue: Date;

  get customDatePickerValue() {
    return this._customDatepickerValue;
  }
  set customDatePickerValue(value) {
    this._customDatepickerValue = value;
    this.change(value);
  }

  get datePickerValue() {
    return this._datePickerValue;
  }
  set datePickerValue(value) {
    this._datePickerValue = value;
    this.customDatePickerValue = moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  }

  writeValue() {}
  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.change = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched() {}
}
```

usage in your components

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <custom-datepicker formControlName="customDatepickerValue"></custom-datepicker>
  </form>

  <pre>{{form.value | json }}</pre>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    customDatepickerValue: new FormControl()
  })
}
```